# Access HTTP method from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I find out what HTTP method was used in rendering the current page?

For example, here's a situation:

```
# button that only links if the record is 'new'
<%= link_to_unless(params[:controller] == "customers" && params[:action] == "new"), ... %>
```

The above works nicely when the form says `customers/new` but not so well if the user passes a failing new form and instead we get `new` rendered by the `create` action. In this case, `params[:action]` is blank and the only way to tell that the above should still link is that the HTTP method is `POST`.

How can I make sure the above `link_to_unless` also fires when the create action fails and renders new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `request.request_method` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do

```
@object_that_was_meant_to_be_created.new_record?
```

Comment: I'm more interested in the general case, where we want to know exactly whether we're dealing with `GET`, `POST`, `UPDATE`, etc.